# Having trouble finding Plantera's Bulb

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I have been playing on hardmode for a while and have beaten the three [**Mechanical Bosses**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanical_Bosses) a couple of times. But I have yet to find a [**Plantera's Bulb**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Plantera%27s_Bulb). It's getting really frustrating.

Does anyone have any methods to finding a Plantera Bulb?

Answer (score 7):

Just before we start, incase you didn't know, bulbs look like this:

[image: Plantera's Bulb In-game]

And minimap:

[image: Plantera's Bulb Minimap]

[**Wiki**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Plantera%27s_Bulb) page.

Now to find Plantera Bulbs, they spawn in the Jungle so you've got to look for them in there...

Now to get started!

There are plenty of methods that can be found online so I have shown some below...

---

> Make vertical tunnels all over the jungle, away just enough to cover all the map with your screen, as soon as you get a plantera bulb on screen, you will see it, because it emits a strong enought pink light, with makes a strong contrast with all the green light sources.
> Making horizontal tunnels may take more time, but will help to more and easier bulbs after you find the previous one.

Excerpt from [**here**](http://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/1z9y5c/i_cant_find_the_plantera_bulb_any_tips/).

---

> 1. Defeat a mechanical boss, preferably the destroyer as its the easiest. Once you have done this you should receive a message stating: 'The jungle grows restless'. This tells you that Chlorophyte, and plants will start spawning in the jungle. It will just take time now for the plants to grow (apparently a Plantera's Bulb will spawn every night).
> 2. While you're waiting, explore the whole of the jungle area so you can view it on your map whilst keeping an eye out for Plantera's bulb. if you use a spelunker potion you may find one easier as it will glow slightly. The Bulb is pink, check the wiki for a picture if you wish. (**Shown above**)
> 3. Now, Planteras bulb is not as pink as the other plants on the map, it is more of a 'peach' colour or a 'faint' pink. Once you have explored the whole of the jungle area, simply check your map regularly whilst you are doing other things and keep an eye out for a peach/faint pink coloured square (icon) the same size as a pink plant square (icon). This way you will not have to keep wasting time running around the jungle looking.
> 4. If you find one, save before you smash it because you might die fighting him and sometimes Plantera doesn't spawn apparently. So you can simply re-load if you have any problems.

Excerpt from [**here**](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/terraria/235194-planteras-bulb-how-find-finally.html).

---

Good luck finding your bulbs, happy hunting!

Answer (score -3):

I've found that if you don't spawn any hard mode ore its easier to find because on the map the ore is the same color as the bulb