# I need help finding and killing Planterra

Tags: terraria-console

I have Terraria for the Xbox 360, and I'm having trouble defeating Planterra. I have found his bulb twice, cleared out approximately a 70 by 50 area, yet I get defeated when he changes form. I've got a turtle armor set, and obsidian shield, blue horseshoe ballon, frozen wings, charm of myths, and lightning boots. I have fire gauntlet i just made but not sure what to replace, my total defense is 87.

I'm using a megashark with chlorophyte bullets, and a chlorophyte saber.

What am I doing wrong? What can I change

I cant find his bulb anymore, I unfortunately have a huge underground jungle system

Comment: For finding the Bulb, check my answer on this previous question. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193861/having-trouble-finding-planteras-bulb-on-xbox-360/193896#193896

Answer (score 1):

Finding another bulb can take time.  One spawns every in-game day and it's possible you've exhausted your bulbs (Plantera bulbs will not spawn until all Mechanical Bosses are defeated).  It helps to clear out long level stretches for plants to grow on (as George Willcox noteS) and keep them cleared out to encourage bulb spawns.  At least the time you spend molding and shaping your jungle will yield more bulb spawns!

As for Plantera, many usual strategies apply.

1. **The Arena** You say you've cleared out an arena, that's good.  I assume you've got layers of platforms you can jump between?  If you haven't done that, do.  Have you stocked the arena with passive healing sources?  Camp fires and heart lamps really help keep your regeneration up and should be standard features in any arena.  Make sure you add some if you have not.
2. **The Potions** are you using any potions?  You should be using Ironskin, Regeneration, Swiftness at minimum.  Siftness does not stack with boots, but it allows you to free up an accessory slot if need be in many boss fights.  Said slot can go to more defense, damage, or utility as need dictates.  You should have the Well Fed buff, pumpkin pie is an easy and excellent source.  It provides a boost to many statistics as well as regen.   Thorns won't hurt - you, that is - and every little bit of damage helps.  An Endurance Potion is an excellent idea but they're more difficult to make - requires fishing and patience.  Potions that increase your damage with your chosen form of offense can help too (be it melee, ranged, magic, or summons) though I frequently skip them.  You should also be using Greater Healing potions for heals, are you?
3. **The Gear**

*Obsidian shield* (or *Cobalt* but might as well make it Obsidian) is mandatory as usual.  There are times when Plantera is going to put you in bad position and the only alternative is to move through him. You'll take damage but the knockback prevention will allow you to do it.

*Wings* are another must IMO so you're covered there.  Just use the best you have access to.

*Jumping/falling accessories* - (ballons, horseshoes, bottles) are not necessary.  Your wings should allow you to get to whatever heights you need to and they prevent falling damage.  Ditch the horseshoe balloon for something else.

*Boots* - you can go with swiftness and use something else here as well, if you want.

*Charm of Myths* - a great accessory for any fight.  More frequent potions and even more health regen.

As for what else to use. . . an emblem of your damage type is a good idea.  So are upgrades like the Avenger Emblem (remember you can stack the Avenger Emblem with any of the base emblems).  If you want to melee, the Fire Gauntlet is very good.  There's nothing wrong with using multiple types of weapons on him but you can arguably benefit more by gearing for *ranged* or *melee* only.  Though some people like to make ichor bullets/arrows to apply the Ichor Debuff to bosses.  It reduces defenses.

One other accessory to consider.

*The Cross Necklace* - makes you invincible for longer after being hit.  Combined with the Obsidian Shield this really helps out in boss fights.  Star Veil is fine too but the falling stars are just as likely to get snagged on the top of the arena as not.  It's the Cross Necklace that makes the upgrade shine in any case.

And lastly, how is your money?  You might consider reforging for defense or +%damage onto your accessories, and aiming for something really good on your weapons (the best enchant for a weapon depends on the weapon type.  It's usually godly for melee though).  87 defense is a lot, so offensive modes on your accessories might be the way to go.  Reforging can get very expensive but can be a huge help.

4. **Plantera Specific Tips**  There aren't many, alas.  I find doing a summoner works really well, honestly.  But I have typically employed the Optic Staff for this and you might not have a black lens to make one.  When I do summoner, I make sure to get at least 5 summons (and I use low defense summoner armor).  The spiky balls that Plantera produces will fall through wooden planks, as you have doubtless noticed at this point.  They hurt the most of all of his attacks and it's best to avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I usually fight Plantera with a friend. I use my Mega Shark with cloriphytre bullets. I use a Cross Necklace. A Cross Necklace allows a few seconds of invisibility after being hit. I mine out a large area and place platforms everywhere. I put campfires on the platforms. When I run out of Cloriphyte Bullets, I use my Legendary Terra Blade to kill him/her. I made my Terra blade Legendary by going to the Goblin Tinkerer and reforged it over and over again until it was Legendary.
    Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

When fighting Plantera, I'd recommend using a Mega Shark with crystal, ichor, or cursed bullets. (Chlorophyte bullets are best, but these may not be practical) Some other magic items such as the venom staff are useful. Clearing out a large area like you've done is helpful, along with using a grapping hook and wings (If you have them). I'd recommend destroying the grass wall behind, this may be a pain - but it stops Plantera from clinging on to the walls; this results in Plantera having lowered mobility. campfires and heart lanterns are a must, and heart statues are useful.

On the matter of finding the bulb, if you have lots of bushes and plants like this:

[image: Bush]

Then destroy them to give more room for the bulb to spawn, the more ground there is, the more chance the bulb has of spawning. It is just a random chance, you'll just have to wait and keep checking. Clear out lots of ground to help the bulb to spawn, and do check back often.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

Try beetle armor and a dragon mask hoverboard and some other cool stuff for your terrairians make a long space to fight plantera in and I mean REALLY big! and get like a Terra Beam or a Death Sickle and in the place you are gonna fight plantera in put some fire places all around and with the Terra Beam and Death Sickle it doesn't use MANA awesome right? [image]

Comment: Hi K. Moore and welcome to Arqade! I appreciate your artwork but can't really understand what you are saying in your answer. Is there any way you could [edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/267605/edit) it to clarify what you mean?