# What do I have to do to summon Plantera?

Tags: terraria

I really want to fight Plantera, because I have all the gear and stuff. But there's one problem; I don't know how to summon it. What do I have to do to summon Plantera?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193861/having-trouble-finding-planteras-bulb

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a item in the Jungle called **Plantera's Bulb**, and destroy it:

> Plantera's Bulb is an object found in the Underground Jungle which can be destroyed with a Pickaxe. When destroyed, it summons Plantera.
>   <sub>[Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Plantera%27s_Bulb)</sub>

In regards to how to find it, have a look at this answer: [**Having trouble finding Plantera's Bulb**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/193896/28182)

Answer (score 2):

You have to defeat all of the Hard Mode Bosses first before Plantera can be summoned. After that, there's a message that says,

> The jungle grows restless.

This means Plantera is abled to be summoned. Find a jungle and look for **Plantera's Bulb**. Destroy the Bulb, and it will be summoned.