# I can't seem to find Plantera's bulbs

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I've beat Wall of Flesh so I'm on hard mode, and I did all Mech bosses, it's been way more than half a day and I've explored 90% of the jungle. But I can't seem to locate Plantera's bulb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having trouble finding planteras bulb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193861/having-trouble-finding-planteras-bulb)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment (and I'm surprised none of the two people who upvoted that comment did so)

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that Plantera's bulb will spawn only in [Underground Jungle](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Underground_Jungle) biome, not the normal one.

You know that bulbs will start spawning only once you get the status message

> The jungle grows restless...

Answer (score 1):

You can make an artificial underground jungle biome with enough mud and jungle seeds underground (The depth meter and looking at the background will help you see if you're deep enough.)

The mud might get in the way of the battle so you can use actuators on the mud after you break the bulb so it doesn't get in the way.

Sometimes other plants or vines will grow so carefully remove them so that the bulb has more room to spawn.

Comment: Hi paisliestpaisley, welcome to Arqade! This reads more as a comment to the existing answer than an answer on its own.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/318830)